# Java: PriorityQueue<Set<Object>> comparator and implementation

Tags: java, set, comparator, priority-queue

I have an object called Event. I used to save those Events to:

```
Queue<Event> Q = new PriorityQueue<>(new EventCompare());
```

but now I figure it out that it would be better, if I have Queue of Sets:

```
Queue<Set<Event>> Q = new PriorityQueue<>(new EventCompare());
```

In my Comparator I compare values of Events.

```
private class EventCompare implements Comparator<Event> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
        if(e1.getValue() > e2.getValue()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(e1.getValue() < e2.getValue()) {
            return -1;
        }


        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now I want that if two values are equal, are in the same Set. So queue should look like this:

```
{Event(1)}, {Event(12)}, {Event(15), Event(15)}.
```

I hope that I was clear enough. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the purpose of having multiple sets? A PriorityQueue already provides you the order that you have shown and allows you to process the event "sets" in that order.

Comment: if you need to compare sets, write a `Comparator<Set<Event>>`

Comment: @RubioRic, I want to have elements with the same value in the set.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But you got any functional or technical reason? You need a PriorityQueue to process events in an specific order. Why do you need them to be wrapped in a set to be processed?

Comment: @RubioRic, I want to implement sweep line alg. described here: http://people.inf.elte.hu/fekete/algoritmusok_msc/terinfo_geom/konyvek/Computational%20Geometry%20-%20Algorithms%20and%20Applications,%203rd%20Ed.pdf. I have to distinguish which is starting point, which is ending.. When sorting, I want to put the same points in one set, but later distinguish them.

Comment: And what is your question, specifically?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've not read the paper throroughly but in pag.26 (of the paper, 36 in the PDF) SETS are mentioned. I think that they are used as an additional structure, to store points that share a characteristic. But it seems that there is no such thing as a queue for sets.